# How to delete local storage when uninstalling an electron app which uses squirrel

Tags: node.js, electron, squirrel.windows

I have an electron.js application where I am trying to clear the local storage of the application on uninstalling the application. The application's installer/uninstaller depends Squirrel.Windows. I have tried the following code using [electron.session](https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/master/docs/api) on `--squirrel-uninstall` event, but that does not work

```
try {
  // clear storage data on uninstall
  const defaultSession = session.defaultSession;
  defaultSession.clearStorageData();
  defaultSession.clearCache()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same question, have you gotten this clear?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was this code:

```
const sessionDataFolder = app.getPath(`sessionData`);
const localStorageFolder = path.join(sessionDataFolder, `Local Storage`);

await fs.rm(localStorageFolder, { force: true, recursive: true });
```

I also tried the `session.defaultSession.clearStorageData()` or instantiating an invisible `BrowserWindow` object and doing `window.webContents.session.clearStorageData()` or even calling `window.webContents.executeJavaScript("localStorage.clear();", true);` but any interaction with `session` or `window.webContents` ended up with the app to immediately exit without any exceptions.